# Grammatical determination of Zochreinu (as in זָכְרֵנוּ לְחַיִּים)

Tags: hebrew, language

Can someone please help me determine the form of the word זָכְרֵנוּ as it appears in the Amida in the Ten Days of Repentance. Looking at the translation I was guessing it to be the imperative plural in present tense of זכר, but I can not find this conjugation in verb tables and Gesenius did not help me neither so far. Please help =)

Comment: Guys. Asking for grammar help is not off-topic. Asking for grammar help independent of Judaism is. As this is very much related to Judaism (davening) this is most certainly on-topic.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is a singular masculine imperative, with a first-person plural pronominal suffix that functions as the object of the verb.

Comment: It is a combination of the two words  זכר and אותנו - Remember us.